# jQuery - not able to consistently access created DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm working with jQuery (version `3.2.1`), and I'm finding that sometimes, for reasons that I cannot discern, jQuery is unable to locate jQuery-created DOM elements. I would say that this issue occurs about 1 out of every 10 times I refresh the page. In those instances, the element is `undefined`.

It's a bit of a long and involved script, so I'll attempt to distill it to its critical parts. First of all, the scripts are introduced in the `index.html` like so:

```
<body>
...
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Pretty much what you'd expect. Here's the relevant (and abbreviated) code from `app.js` - the problem occurs in the `loadItems()` function:

```
function getQueryParamCat(queryParam) {
  return $('.category-item[data-query_name=' + '\'' + queryParam + '\'' + ']');
}

function loadItems(queryParam) {
    $.post('./get_items.php', {}, () => {
        const queryParamCat = getQueryParamCat(queryParam);

        if (queryParamCat[0]) {
          // Leaving out categoryClick() - it triggers a click on the relevant DOM element
          categoryClick(queryParamCat);
        } else {
          categoryClick($('category').first());
        }
    });
}

function loadCategories(callBack) {
  $.post('./get_categories.php', {}, (data) => {
    const categories = $.parseJSON(data);
    $.each(categories, (i, value) => {
      const cat = $('<category>').appendTo($('left')).html(value.name);
      cat.attr('class', 'category-item');
      cat.attr('data-query_name', value.name.toLowerCase());
      cat.mousedown(function () {
        categoryClick($(this));
      });
    });

    return callBack;
  });
}

$(document).ready(() => {
  // Leaving out getParameterByName() - just gets a string from the url
  const queryParam = getParameterByName();
  loadCategories(loadItems(queryParam));  
});
```

In brief summary:

- the page loads and `loadCategories()` is called.
- the client makes an AJAX request to `get_categories.php`, and the returned data is used to create a set of `<category>` DOM elements.
- `loadItems(queryParam)` is then called as a callback, which then makes an additional AJAX request to get more data.
- In the callback following that request, we ultimately want to call the `categoryClick()` function, passing in a `<category>` DOM element as the argument (the element to be 'clicked'). THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM OCCURS.

About 1 out of 10 times, the result of `getQueryParamCat()` comes back as `r.fn.init [prevObject: r.fn.init(1)]`, which makes the value of `queryParamCat[0]` in the conditional in `loadItems()` evaluate to `undefined`. However, in those situations, `$('category')` also evaluates to `r.fn.init [prevObject: r.fn.init(1)]`, meaning that `$('category').first()` is also `undefined`.

This problem only seems to affect elements that are created by jQuery - anything that was hard-coded in the HTML can be accessed, no problem. Why is it that jQuery is unable to consistently find these elements? Is it trying to find those elements before they've been successfully appended? I could understand if it failed all the time, but the inconsistency is confusing to me. Can anyone offer any suggestions as to how to make this code perform reliably?

Comment: Wrap everything in `$(document).ready(() => {...` Are you sure you want to use the arrow? It has no `this`...What's a <category> DOM element XML.. ?

Comment: You've created a race condition. Learn about Promises and how to use them from jQuery's `$.post()`

Comment: Do you use `dataType: "xml",`?

Comment: `loadItems(queryParam)` is executing in the argument, and returning nothing. AJAX is, of course, Asynchronous. So, if you want to load one after the other, it needs to be inside the other `$.post()` request in your case.

Comment: Thanks @PHPglue, that was it.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I had thought that the way I was passing the function as a callback would've handled the race condition, but it seems that I had misunderstood how the callback was being executed. Interestingly, I did experiment with jQuery promises (for this client, can't use ES6), but was encountering the same problem with those - that's why I didn't immediately jump to 'race condition'. I can only assume I was using them incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Odd syntax; `loadCategories` expects a callback as an argument, but `loadItems` doesn't return anything, so `loadCategories(loadItems(queryParam));` turns into `loadCategories(undefined);`.

Also, `return callBack;` doesn't do anything inside of a `$.post` function; it's not only not returning the value to the outer function's caller, it's also running async.

Maybe did you mean to do something like this?

```
loadCategories(() => {
  loadItems(queryParam)
});

function loadCategories(callBack) {
  // ...
  $.each(categories, (i, value) => {
  // ...


  });
  callBack();
```

That ensures the callback is called after the meat of loadCategories is done.

Comment: Perfect, thank you - didn't realize that the callback wasn't working as I had planned. It was really just that simple.